# Can one obtain eigenstates of the Hamiltonian from solutions to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

The time-dependent Schrodinger equation

$$  i \frac{\partial }{\partial t} |\psi(t)\rangle = H|\psi(t)\rangle $$

has the general solution expanded in terms of eigenstates $\{ |n \rangle \}$ of the Hamiltonian $H$ as

$$ |\psi(t) \rangle = \sum_n c_n e^{-iE_nt} |n\rangle $$

where $H |n\rangle = E_n |n\rangle$ and $c_n \in \mathbb{C}$. This kind of looks like a Fourier transform and I would expect to be able to invert this equation and solve for the eigenstates $|n\rangle$. If we do the usual trick of inverting a Fourier transform by multiplying both sides by $e^{iE_mt}$ and integrating with respect to $t$, we find

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{i E_mt} |\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_n c_n \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{i(E_m- E_n)t}\right)|n\rangle = 2\pi \sum_n c_n \delta(E_m-E_n) |n\rangle $$

This does not look good because instead of a Kronecker delta which will pick out the eigenstate, we have a Dirac delta .

Is it possible to obtain the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian if we know the solution of the time-dependent Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Maybe the $c_n$ is zero for some values, so you don't get any information for those values of $n$. The math looks good to me, it's not a bra-ket product or anything that should converge

Comment: If the Hamiltonian has $N$ eigenstates, there will be a set of $N$ linearly independent solutions to the TDSE. In terms of the Hamiltonian's eigenbasis, these are of the form  
$\{e^{-iE_nt} |n\rangle\}$. If you know every one of these linearly independent solutions, then you know every solution to the TDSE, and this is equivalent to knowing all the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.